# How to get Highcharts X-Axis Categories starting at the left most point

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a Highcharts area chart, with string categories on the X-Axis.
I want the chart to start at the left most edge of the x-axis and end at the rightmost edge, without any padding. In the image below, the red arrows show the spacing that I want to get rid of. Without text categories this is easily achievable, but with I just can't seem to figure it out.
Any help appreciated, thanks.

[image: Chart with unwanted padding]

Comment: Any luck with this?  I'm trying to figure it out, too, and haven't been able to get anything to work.

Comment: Solutions are either way too complex or unreliable. Highcharts should provide a simple "pad" property, like most other chart libraries.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can achieve the desired result by redefining labels.formatter on axis. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vnJLG/) is here.

But if you want to keep it simple and pass `axis.categories` in traditional way (I think that this is a way more better), I suggest you to use a tiny hack and redefine an `Axis.init` function. Try it on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2S3fK/).

**UPD:** I've updated my previous fiddle a little. [Check it out](http://jsfiddle.net/2S3fK/4/). I think that you can combine all my solution to get a nicer one.

Comment: Thank you!  This is the only working solution here currently. I used the labels.formatter solution.

Comment: The only solution working. OP should mark this as the correct answer

Answer (score 4):

You can use spacingLeft and spacingRight to set the spacing:

```
chart: {
         renderTo: 'chart1',
         type: 'area',
         spacingLeft: -21,      
         spacingRight: -21,      
         spacingBottom: 1
},
```

Answer (score 4):

```
xAxis: {
categories: ['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3', 'cat4', 'cat5']
},
series: [
    {
      name: 'name of series',
      data: [0, 2, 0, 2, 0],
      pointPlacement: 'on',
    }
]
```

This solution worked for me, maybe it helps. I can't confirm whether or not this applies to other ways of inputting data.

Answer (score 3):

A cleaner solution is to use the `pointPlacement` reference provided in the [Highchart API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.area.pointPlacement).

Add `pointPlacement: 'on'` and you should be in business. (For reference, [here is their example JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-pointplacement-between/))

Comment: pointPlacement: 'on' does not solve this problem. pointPlacement: -0.5 sort of does, but then the gap on the other end is doubled.

Answer (score 2):

Just add:

```
...
xAxis: {
  startOnTick: true,
  ...
},
...
```

Comment: @RossDeane In the fiddle you use categories, in your image above it looks like you didn't use categories. Categories have a certain width and the points will always be centered within the category.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did mention string categories in the question, sorry if I wasn't clear. So it can't be done? :(

Comment: Oh right, you mentioned categories. Sorry, but I think categories imply the padding to center the points.

Comment: Hm, OK thats a shame. Thanks again.

Comment: do anyone tell me how to get the **startOnTick** functionality in google charts api for line chart

Answer (score 0):

You need the following settings.

```
xAxis: {           
  plotLines: [{
    value: 0, 
    color: '#color'
  }],
  tickmarkPlacement: 'on'
},
yAxis: {           
  lineWidth: 0,
}
```